# Can Resin4.0.38 support address * in <server> configuration

Tags: configuration, resin

I'm trying to upgrade my webapp from resin 4.0.15 to resin 4.0.38. My problem is **setting address as * in server tag works for resin 4.0.15 while it doesn't for resin 4.0.38**. Snippets of resin.xml are as follows:

Resin 4.0.15:

```
<server id="app" address="*" port="6802"/>
```

Resin 4.0.38:

```
<cluster id="app">
     <server id="app-0" address="*" port="6802"/>
...
```

Exception is thrown in resin 4.0.38 as follows:

```
com.caucho.config.ConfigException: '*' is not a valid cluster IP address because it is not a private network IP address.
    at com.caucho.cloud.topology.CloudServer.<init>(CloudServer.java:151)
    at com.caucho.cloud.topology.TriadServer.<init>(TriadServer.java:50)
    at com.caucho.cloud.topology.CloudPod.createServer(CloudPod.java:443)
    at com.caucho.cloud.topology.CloudPod.createServer(CloudPod.java:419)
    at com.caucho.cloud.topology.CloudPod.createStaticServer(CloudPod.java:332)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.BootPodConfig.initTopology(BootPodConfig.java:189)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.BootPodConfig.initTopology(BootPodConfig.java:158)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.BootClusterConfig.initTopology(BootClusterConfig.java:283)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.BootClusterConfig.initTopology(BootClusterConfig.java:268)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.BootResinConfig.initTopology(BootResinConfig.java:334)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.BootResinConfig.initTopology(BootResinConfig.java:318)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.BootResinConfig.initTopology(BootResinConfig.java:310)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.initTopology(Resin.java:1056)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.initServletSystem(Resin.java:1276)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.configure(Resin.java:998)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.initMain(Resin.java:980)
    at com.caucho.server.resin.Resin.main(Resin.java:1438)
```

Can anyone help me out on this issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve that problem by setting `<server id="app-0" address="0.0.0.0" port="6802"/>`

Technically it has the same effect